# QGIS: Minimum bounding geometry: Convex hull not including all features

Tags: qgis, geometry, convex-hull

I have been using the convex hull tool to create MCPs for various layers (containing location points). For some reason, this layer is not looking like the others and I can't figure out why. It's as if it isn't including all the features and is thus producing a shape not at all representative of the actual spread of points. I have checked the features and found no noticeable errors and I have even tried manually selecting all the features and using the "use selected features only" option when running the convex hull - this hasn't worked.

Am I missing something super basic that is messing up my MCP? I'm using QGIS version 3.1.

[image: Convex hull MCP not including all points]

Comment: Can you share your data?

Comment: Perhaps you should try concave hull instead.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I'm afraid  don't know how

Comment: @Gery okay, would you be able to tell/show me how to do that (i'm a bit of a qgis newbie)

Comment: @AJShiron in QGIS go to Processes -> Toolbox and in the search box type "concave", it should appear under the tab "Vectorial geometry"

Comment: Thanks @Gery I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

I am getting an error for Convex Hull in QGIS 3.16.  Try using the minimum bounding geometry tool from the Processing toolbox.  Minimum bounding geometry has an option for generating a convex hull.  This worked just fine.

Consider submitting a bug report to QGIS.

Comment: This is the method I used and it worked fine for all my other layers but for some reason it looks wacky for this one

Comment: QGIS 3.16.x is EOL (END OF LIFE), so there is no point in reporting the bug.

Comment: @pigreco 3.16.16 is the current long term release version

Comment: @JHG true, but until 02/18/2022